# Using for loop to count a single letter from user input

Tags: python, for-loop, counting

I am struggling with a task, counting a letter from a user input and returning the number of times the letter can be found within the sentence from the input.

this is what I have so far:

```py
sentence = input("write an sentence here: ")

count = 0

for character in sentence:
    if e in character:
        count += 1
    print count
```

I am getting errors. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: How you know what letter do you want to count? Do you ask to the user? Or do you want to cont every different letter/

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Maybe you forget to declare `e`. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count all the letters in string, without spaces, then here you have it:

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
sentence = input("write an sentence here: ")
count = 0

for letter in sentence:
    if letter in letters:
        count+=1
print(count)
```

If you want to search for a certain letter:

```
sentence = input("write an sentence here: ")
count = 0
searchedletter= input("Put your searched letter: ")
for letter in sentence:
    if letter==searchedletter:
        count+=1
print(count)
```